# invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘PVOID {aka void*}’[-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the following code, and I keep getting this error:

> invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘PVOID {aka void*}’[-fpermissive]

I am basically looking to do a simple read-write on external EEPROM using a UMFT201-xb breakout board with the FT201x USB to I2C interface.

I downloaded the example code from the [D2XX EEPROM Programming examples](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_428%20D2XX%20EEPROM%20Programming%20Examples.pdf) and the specific file I am trying to compile that gives me the above error is at `AN_428_D2XX_EEPROM_Programming_Examples/FT-X/FT-X EEPROM Modify/FT-X EEPROM Modify.cpp`.

FYI, I am working on Linux.

This is the specific bit of code it complains about:

```
enter co/Open the port
//********************************************************

for (i = 0; i < numDevs; i++)
{
    if ((Dev_Found == FALSE) && (devInfo[i].Type == FT_DEVICE_X_SERIES))
    {
        Dev_Found = TRUE;

        status = FT_OpenEx("Chipi-X", FT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION, &fthandle);

        if (status != FT_OK)
        {
            printf("Open status not ok %d\n", status);
            printf("Trying to open default EEPROM device...\n");
            status = FT_OpenEx("FT231X USB UART", FT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION, &fthandle);
            if (status != FT_OK)
            {
                printf("Open status not ok %d\n", status);
                printf("\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Open status OK %d\n", status);
                printf("\n");
            }

            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Open status OK %d\n", status);
            printf("\n");
        }
```

The issue arises at the line:

```
status = FT_OpenEx("Chipi-X", FT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION, &fthandle);
```

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your reply. But on casting off the constantness, I get this error: Open status not okay and I have nothing else to work with. "numDevs" in an earlier part of the same code was defined using "DWORD". Could that be the problem, since I'm working on LInux? :/

Comment: You are trying to pass a `const` thing to something taking a non-`const` thing. Bad idea. Compiler is right to complain.

Comment: Your question is off-topic, you need to extract a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The only `void*` parameter in `FT_OpenEx()` is the first parameter:

```
FT_STATUS FT_OpenEx (PVOID pvArg1, DWORD dwFlags, FT_HANDLE *ftHandle)
```

You are passing in a string literal, which in C++ is a `const char[]` that decays to `const char*`. You can't pass a const pointer to a non-const pointer, hence the error.

`FT_OpenEx()` will not modify the content of the first parameter, so you can safely cast away the constness:

```
status = FT_OpenEx(const_cast<char*>("Chipi-X"), ...);
```

Otherwise, you can copy the string data to a non-const buffer first, and then pass that instead:

```
char name[] = "Chipi-X";
status = FT_OpenEx(name, ...);
```

Comment: Concerning `const_cast<char*>("Chipi-X")`: Hopefully, it's just a non-const-correct API. I once tried (just for fun) to overwrite memory at a `const char*` pointer I got from a string literal. It crashed immediately (gcc was clever enough to mark this as read-only). But, it was on Intel x86...

Comment: "cast away the constness" - yes, an *option*. But *please* don't. I've had to debug problems in the past arising from objects initially declared const and being passed as such to functions, having their constness cast away and modified - invoking undefined behaviour. Leading to *very obscure* bugs that were *not* fun to debug.